# Must press "Shut Down" twice to shut down in Xubuntu 15.10

Tags: dual-boot, xubuntu, shutdown, 15.10

I am fairly new to Linux/Ubuntu, and I installed Xubuntu 15.10 on my Windows 10 64-bit PC last week so I can dual-boot. To shut down my computer in Xubuntu, I have to click on "Shut Down" twice before the computer actually powers off. The first time I click it, nothing appears to happen. The second time I click it, Xubuntu shuts down correctly. Is there a way to fix this so I only have to click once?

My specs:

Lenovo Z50-70

- 8GM DDR3 RAM
- 1TB HDD
- Intel Core i7-4510U
- NVIDIA GeForce 840M

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- If you're using **Light Locker**, go to the Control Panel and disable it.
- Afterwards, please run this shell command in order to force a system reboot:

  ```
  sudo telinit 6
  ```

  **Note:** The command above needs to be run even if you're not using Light Locker.
- After restarting your computer, does the problem happen again? Test your system a few times. If the problem persists, open `/etc/default/grub` for editing by running the following command:

  ```
  sudo gedit /etc/default/grub
  ```

  **Note:** If you don't have Gedit, install it by running this command:

  ```
  sudo apt-get install gedit
  ```
- The contents of your `/etc/default/grub` file will look similar to what we see below, except that you'll have to turn `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX=` into `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=force"`:

  ```
  # If you change this file, run 'update-grub' afterwards to update
  # /boot/grub/grub.cfg.

  GRUB_DEFAULT=0
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT=0
  GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=true
  GRUB_TIMEOUT="10"
  GRUB_DISTRIBUTOR=`lsb_release -i -s 2> /dev/null || echo Debian`
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"
  GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX="acpi=force"

  # Uncomment to disable graphical terminal (grub-pc only)
  #GRUB_TERMINAL=console
  ```
- Now run this command in order to update GRUB and force a system restart:

  ```
  sudo update-grub && sudo telinit 6
  ```

If the problem still persists, click "Shut Down" **only once**, then run the following commands and paste their output here:

```
dmesg
uname -a
```

Comment: Thanks Yuri; I had to edit the grub file and update Grub as you described, but I think that did the trick. I restarted Xubuntu five or six times just to make sure, and I haven't had any problems so far.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad to hear your problem is solved. If you wish, in XUbuntu you can go to the keyboard settings and define a shortcut for "telinit 6" (forced restart). In XUbuntu/Xfce, you can access the keyboard settings by type-searching "keyboard" at the whisker menu. In the shell terminal window, the respective command is **xfce4-keyboard-settings**, then go to the "Application shortcuts" tab, hit the "Add" button, type the command **gksu telinit 6**, click the "OK" button, then hit a key combo of your choice (e.g. hold the keys **Ctrl**, **Alt** and **Backspace**) and it's done.

Comment: Okay, I may do that. Do you know if there's a way I can still suspend my session/be required to sign back in if I close the laptop lid? Or will I have to manually log out before I close the lid?

Comment: Fully install Xscreensaver (**sudo apt-get install xscreensaver xscreensaver-data xscreensaver-data-extra xscreensaver-gl xscreensaver-gl-extra**), then go to the Xfce Control Panel (**xfce4-settings-manager**), open the Screen Saver preferences and click the Advanced tab. At the top right corner you'll find some power management preferences. Xscreensaver has some very neat screensavers, too: check out Abstractile, AntInspect, BoxFit, Fireworkx, FluidBalls, GLMatrix, GLSchool, GLText, Intermomentary, Juggler3D, Molecule, Pyro, SpeedMine, Squiral, Substrate, Tangram, Vermiculate, Wormhole...

Comment: Oh, I forgot to mention how to deal with the notebook lid. Well: open the Xfce Control Panel, then access the Power Manager (from the terminal: **xfce4-power-manager-settings**). You'll find plenty of options (Suspend, Hibernate etc.).

Comment: This did not work for my Xubuntu 19.10 which was demonstrating the same issue as the OP. Issue continues. The upgrade to 19.10 introduced the issue

Comment: @NormanBird This is likely a new bug or (less likely) a previous bug that was reintroduced during the latest system (kernel and drivers) upgrades. My answer above applied to former Ubuntu 15.10 and I'm currently using the 64-bit XUbuntu version 16.04.6 (I've not migrated to any recent version yet). **In a nutshell**: it's recommended that you add a **new question** reporting this issue, because it's more likely that some of the linuxists using the same version (19.10) of *Ubuntu has already found a solution or maybe a workaround.

Comment: @NormanBird You may want to try using `acpi=off` instead of `acpi=force` in the GRUB config file (don't forget to run `sudo update-grub` afterwards and then reboot), in order to check if the issue that you're experiencing is ACPI-related: if by turning ACPI off you still experience this problem, then ACPI is not the root cause. I'm currently using kernel version `4.14.14-041414-generic`, which does not have this bug: you may want to try different kernels as explained at https://askubuntu.com/a/142000/389062 (see also https://wiki.ubuntu.com/Kernel/MainlineBuilds).