# After shutdown button is clicked, only files on desktop disappear and it just stays like this

Tags: 18.04, shutdown

After I click the shutdown button on the top right corner on ubuntu 18.04.2 and click Shutdown on the new window, nothing happens, except all the files on my desktop disappear. After clicking the shutdown button in the top right corner once again, the computer just shuts down immediately.

Writing "shutdown now" into the terminal works as usual.

After reboot, the files on my desktop are there again.

This has occured to me after having ubuntu for half a year already.

This doesn't cause me any issues, but is kind of annoying.

Comment: Related: https://askubuntu.com/questions/698294/must-press-shut-down-twice-to-shut-down-in-xubuntu-15-10